# android-cmake with NDK r9b on Windows 7 x64

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to compile third party library which use CMake build system to compile.
I have windows 7 x64 and Android NDK R9b .I downloaded cmake-android from https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake and set environment variable(ANDROID_NDK) to point to root directory of android NDK.

then i trying to compile the things with cmake-gui where I select android.toolchain.cmake file when asked in wizard but it says "Could not find any working toolchain in the NDK.  Probably your Android NDK is broken." I have tried even previous version of NDK too it gives same error. same things works perfectly on Linux Machine.

I attached screenshot of cmake-gui

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For 64 bit systems you need to set the following in CMake

ANDROID_NKD_HOST_X64=1

Sorry for the late answer, but it took me a while to find this solution and I thought it might help others who are searching for it.

Comment: Where?? Where do I set this??

Answer (score 1):

I think you must generate toolchain.

Check here:
http://android-cmake.googlecode.com/hg/documentation.html